# Остановить код до нажатия кнопки

Tags: asp.net

У меня есть 2 веб формы. На первой из них я нажимаю на кнопку, и должна открываться вторая форма. Но помимо этого в экшене этой кнопке дальше идёт код инсерта в таблицу. А данные для заполнения берутся с текстбокса со второй формы. И мне нужно что бы после открытия второй формы дальнейший код тормозился и ждал, пока я на 2 форме заполню текстбокс и нажму кнопку Ок. Вот мой код кнопки на первой странице.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "window.open", "window.open('WebForm4.aspx')", true);
    con.Open();
    OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand(web.Brigade_Insert(TextBox1.Text), con);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    FillGrid();
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно осуществить. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: я не силён в wpf, но по логике стоит вызов формы оформить в отдельный метод, а при нажатии запускать Thread th = new Thread(метод вызывающий форму);  th.Start();  th.Join();

Comment: Либо я вас не совсем понял, либо такого в ASP.NET по просту нет.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296188/how-to-use-threads-in-asp-net тут пример использования threads в asp.net

Comment: Да но мне нужно не по времени слипить, а немного по другому. Попробую объяснить. Вот пример из windows.forms как я делал там. `Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            if (f3.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` То есть по нажатию этой кнопки, открывалась новая форма. С текстбоксами которые я заполнял. На ней была кнопка OK со свойством диалог резаулт ок. И когда я заполнял все текст боксы я нажимал на эту кнопку. И только тогда эта вторая форма закрывалась. А управление кодом передавалось назад в первую нажатую мной кнопку на первой форме и продолжалось дальнейшее выполнение кода. Вот что нужно.

Comment: @Андрей Веб так не работает. Отучайтесь. Здесь нет блокирующего `ShowModal`, который не возвращается в вызывающий код то тех пор, пока модальное окно не закроется. Начинайте читать про AJAX и jQuery.

Comment: ну, насколько я понял вопрос: можно попробовать ввести глобальную статическую булевую переменную-триггер, которая будет включаться в нужный момент (пока вы заполняете формы), и закрываться в нужный момент. Основной код должен запускаться в отдельном потоке, отслеживать переменную-триггер, и останавливаться, пока она активна. Но к сожалению я растерял все свои экстрасенсорные способности, и по представленному фрагменту кода нельзя сказать ровным счётом ничего. Что там делает основной поток, когда вызывается нужная форма. Очень много пробелов в вопросе.

Comment: @Garrus_En Пожалуйста, не путайте человека с потоками и глобальными переменными (в ASP.NET?!). Здесь проблема в разделении логики между сервером/клиентом и передачи данных между ними.