# Обращение к элементам другой страницы

Tags: asp.net

Здравствуйте. А в ASP.NET можно как то обратиться к элементам с другой страницы. Например к баттону который находится на другой странице. Я пробовал на подобии в windows.forms вот так вот:

```
WebForm4 wf = new WebForm4();
```

А потом уже с помощью переменной wf обратиться например к кнопке. Но пока что я так смог обращаться только к функциям с других страниц. Если как то можно обращаться к элементам подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: я уже писал Вам (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649453), что объекты веб форм создаются инфраструктурой ASP.NET в ответ на запросы с клиента и живут очень короткое время. Создание их "вручную" в коде приложения - бессмысленно.

Comment: Хорошо спасибо. А вот тогда ещё вопрос подобного рода. Я на вызванной странице читаю из текстбокса значение. И потом ретёрню его в функции 

        `public String Number
        {
            get
            {
                return ViewState["str"].ToString();
            }
        }` И после нажатия кнопки ok возвращаюсь на первую страницу а там уже с помощью `WebForm4 wf = new WebForm4();
            string str = wf.Number;` пытаюсь передать значение. Но оно уже по нулям. Я думал вьюстейт сохраняет значения даже между страниц или я что то не так понял? Как можно передать значение?

Comment: ViewState - это такой мешок, куда разные контролы и Ваш код могут положить что угодно (с условием, что это может сериализовано - переведено в текстовый вид и обратно). Потом, когда страница генерит html для клиента, все содержимое этого мешка переводится в текстовый вид и записывается в одно из hidden полей формы (- щелкните в браузере правой кнопкой мыши на странице, выбирете "View source" и внимательно изучите). Когда происходит submit формы браузером (в терминах ASP.NET - PostBack), значения всех полей ввода (input/select/textarea), включая и инпут с ViewState, отправляются на сервер.

Comment: На сервере каждый контрол достает из Request.Form то, что ему надо, и только поэтому мы можем из контролов получить значения введенные пользователем, а из ViewState - то, что туда положили.

Comment: Спасибо, я как раз сейчас и попробовал использовать респонс редирект и вроде всё нормально.

Comment: @Igor вы не могли бы взлянуть на мой вопрос по адресу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/652241/reportviewer-asp-net-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%B0 Может быть сможете чем то помочь. Очень нужно решить эту проблему. Спасибо заранее.